# Event.RESIZE doesn't fire on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, resize

I didn't find any discussion regarding the following resize-issue:

iOS signals when you've created a personal hotspot, make a sound recording (and some other notifications) by changing the size and color of the status bar - that status bar's height doubles and the viewport for apps is moved down the y-axis.

If I manually check for stage.fullScreenHeight it reflects this.

Now I would expect Actionscript to notify me with an Event.RESIZE just like it does when the orientation is changed. But the event won't fire.

How do you guys solve this issue? Is there another event firing that I don't think of?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detective the changing of the size of status bar (when under hotspot...), you can add this kind of notification:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>                                              selector:@selector(statusBarFrameWillChangeNotification:)
>                                                  name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
>                                                object:nil];

in viewdidLoad method;

Then in statusBarFrameWillChangeNotification method, change the size of the view frame in view controller to suit the status bar size.